# Iterative Learning Algorithm to adjust a vector to get best result (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I wrote an algorithm that calculates some kinds of features of some candidates, The features are stored in a dataframe e.g.: (c1 is candidate1)

```
    feature1    feature2    feature3    ...
c1  score1_1    score1_2    score1_3    ...
c2  score2_1    score2_2    score2_3    ...
...
cn  scoren_1    scoren_2    scoren_3    ...
```

I wrote a function that gets a vector of weights (it's length is the number of features) and calculates a column of total score (multiplication of the vector at each line gives the score of that line's candidate)

Then I take the top N candidates (got the highest score, lets say N=10) and compare them to another tool's output on the same candidates, wrote an algorithm to get a score out of this comparison, basically its weighted intersection, mark this score as S.

I do that for a few sets of candidates, for the same vector of weights, and calculate the average of S, mark the average as S_avg.

I want to do the above iteratively, adjust the vector of weights each iteration in order to maximize S_avg, does anyone have any suggestion for simple iterative way to do that (the vector adjustment) in Python?

Thanks, hope I was clear enough

EDIT: I forgot to mention there is an invariant, sum of the weights is 1, each feature gives score from 0 to 1, so total score will also have to be in the range 0-1

Comment: So you want to do linear regression?

Comment: Umm I'm not sure how can linear regression determine the weights vector I should use for the next iteration...